# SQL query for selecting all but needing aliases

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to perform a join operation on two tables linked by item IDs.  However, the problem with them is that they've got columns with the same name as follows:

```
items
(ID, **Quantity**, etc. /*[nothing in etc. is shared by status' columns]*/)

status
(ID, **Quantity**, etc. /*[nothing in etc. is shared by items' columns]*/)
```

I want to get all records from these tables and join them, but I don't know what the SQL query would look like.  I know it'd be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
LEFT OUTER JOIN status
ON items.ID = status.ID
```

and I know I need aliases for the two quantity columns (which I know how to do), but where does the latter part of the query fit in?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I recommend avoiding `SELECT *` queries. Just select the specific columns you need, and if there are duplicate column names you can easily assign aliases for them.

```
SELECT i.col1, i.col2, i.quantity AS item_quantity, s.col3, s.col4, s.quantity AS status_quantity
FROM items AS i
JOIN status AS s ON i.ID = s.ID
```

But if you really need to select all columns, you can use the solution in Marc B's answer.